# Why Laravel-json-api update does not work?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.8, json-api

I created an API with the Laravel-json-api framework, with no controller, since the framework do all the job.

It works fine with index and read, not with update.

I use Postman to do an update, but it returns the record in the DB, without any change, nor any error message.

the api.php file :

```
JsonApi::register('v1')->routes(function ($api) {
        $api->resource('titre')->only('index', 'read', 'update');
});
```

To update the titre record, I use /localhost/api/v1/titre/777777
I use Postman, with the right Content-Type : application/vnd.api+json

And here is my Postman's raw body :

```
{
     "data": {
        "type": "titre",
        "id": "777777",
        "attributes": {
            "ACTIF": "O",
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost/api/v1/titre/777777"
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the API to update the ACTIF attribute, but I get as a result :

```
{
     "data": {
        "type": "titre",
        "id": "777777",
        "attributes": {
            "ACTIF": "D",
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost/api/v1/titre/777777"
        }
    }
}
```

No error message, or anything, but the ACTIF attribute, which should be updated from D to O, is not updated.

According to the Laravel-json-api documentation, this should work, right ?
Can someone tells me where is my error ?

Comment: For updating did you use the PUT method? [This tutorial](https://howtojsonapi.com/laravel.html) tells us to do so.

Comment: No, I used the PATCH request.  
PUT is not supported by the {json:api} specification. I also send a message to this tutorial's author to indicate he used the PUT method instead of the PATCH method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing might be caused by several reasons. Please check these points:

- Make sure that you are using `PATCH` HTTP method for updates. JSON:API specification [explicitly requires `PATCH` for updates](https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating).
- Make sure that `ACTIF` attribute is fillable if you are using Eloquent Adapter. Laravel JSON API [relies on mass assignment feature](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/adapters/).

If this doesn't work, please include a [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) request in your question as it helps us to reproduce your request.

Comment: Yes, I use PATCH, I know PUT is not supported by {json:api}. And you are right, the ACTIF attribute was not fillable. It works now, thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome. Glad that I could help you. Would be great if you could accept the answer to help other ones.